# McCormick envelope of two variables which are also defined in terms of an envelope

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, constraints

I have a equation which is defined as $\langle\langle x_ix_j\rangle^M\langle \cos(\theta)\rangle^C\rangle^M$ where $M$ is the McCormick envelope of product of variables $x_ix_j$ and $C$ is defined as envelope of cosine function.

The McCormick envelope is defined as
\begin{align*}
\langle x_ix_j\rangle^M &= \{ \alpha \ge x_i^lx_j+x_j^lx_i-x_i^lx_j^l \\
&\qquad \alpha \ge x_i^ux_j+x_j^ux_i-x_i^ux_j^u \\
&\qquad \alpha \le x_i^lx_j+x_j^ux_i-x_i^lx_j^u \\
&\qquad \alpha \le x_i^ux_j+x_j^lx_i-x_i^ux_j^l\},
\end{align*}
where $x^l,x^u$ are constants for both $x_i,x_j$ and known.

The envelope for cosine function is defined as
\begin{align*}
\langle \cos(\theta)\rangle^C &= \{\beta \le 1-\frac{1-\cos(\theta^m)}{(\theta^m)^2}\theta^2\\
&\qquad \beta\ge\frac{\cos(\theta^l)-\cos(\theta^u)}{(\theta^l-\theta^u)}(\theta-\theta^l)+\cos(\theta^l)\},
\end{align*}
where $\theta^l,\theta^u,\theta^m$ are constants and known.

Now, I have to define the McCormick envelope of $\langle\langle x_ix_j\rangle^M\langle cos(\theta)\rangle^C\rangle^M$. Is it equivalent/true to write $\langle\langle x_ix_j\rangle^M\langle \cos(\theta \rangle^C\rangle^M$ as
\begin{align*}
\langle\langle x_ix_j\rangle^M\langle \cos(\theta)\rangle^C\rangle^M = \langle \alpha \beta \rangle^M &= \{ \gamma \ge \alpha^l\beta+\beta^l\alpha-\alpha^l\beta^l \\
&\qquad \gamma \ge \alpha^u\beta+\beta^u\alpha-\alpha^u\beta^u \\
&\qquad \gamma \le \alpha^l\beta+\beta^u\alpha-\alpha^l\beta^u \\
&\qquad \gamma \le \alpha^u\beta+\beta^l\alpha-\alpha^u\beta^l\}?
\end{align*}
If this is true, then how to define $\alpha^l,\alpha^u,\beta^l,\beta^u$? Do the first two inequalities of $\langle x_ix_j\rangle^M$ becomes the lower limit for $\alpha$ and the last two ineqaulites of $\langle x_ix_j\rangle^M$ becomes upper limit of $\alpha$? Or is there any other/better way to define McCormick envelope for such equation?